# How can I activate child category in treeview on the vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, treeview, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two vue components.

My first component (parent component) like this:

```
<template>
    ...
        <ul class="filter-category" v-for="list in categories">
            <list-category :data="list" :category-id="categoryId"></list-category>
        </ul>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        data() {
            return {
                categories: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'England',
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 3,
                                name: 'Chelsea',
                                children: [
                                    {id: 7, name: 'Hazard'},
                                    {id: 8, name: 'Morata'}
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                id: 4,
                                name: 'Manchester United',
                                children: [
                                    {id: 9, name: 'Pogba'},
                                    {id: 10, name: 'Lukaku'}
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Spain',
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 5,
                                name: 'Real Madrid',
                                children: [
                                    {id: 11, name: 'Ronaldo'},
                                    {id: 12, name: 'Bale'}
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                id: 6,
                                name: 'Barcelona',
                                children: [
                                    {id: 13, name: 'Messi'},
                                    {id: 14, name: 'Suarez'}
                                ]
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                categoryId: 7
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My second component (child component) like this:

```
<template>
    <li>
        <!--parent-->
        <a v-if="isFolder" href="javascript:" @click="toggle">
            <span class="fa fa-fw" :class="icon"></span> {{data.name}}
        </a>
        <!--if not folding, we do not need an binding event-->
        <a v-else href="javascript:" :title="data.name"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></span> {{data.name}}</a>
        <!--children-->
        <ul v-if="isFolder" :class="isShow">
            <list-category v-for="(data, index) in data.children" :key="index" :data="data" :search="search"></list-category>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['data', 'categoryId'],
        data() {
            return {
                open: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            icon() {
                return {
                    'fa-plus': !this.open,
                    'fa-minus': this.open,
                }
            },
            isFolder() {
                return this.data.children && this.data.children.length
            },
            isShow() {
                return this.open ? 'show': 'hide'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                this.open = !this.open
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If prop `categoryId` = `id` category in data `categories`, then I want the category active.

In my code, I want if the code executed, category hazard active like this:

==========================================================================

[image]

==========================================================================

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two actually missing things:

- You have to add the [conditional **class** attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) (`:class="{active: data.id === categoryId}"`) using the Object Syntax:

  ```
    <a v-else href="javascript:" :title="data.name" :class="{active: data.id === categoryId}"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></span> {{data.name}}</a>
  ```
- You have to pass `categoryId` down the component tree (`:category-id="categoryId"`):

  ```
    <ul v-if="isFolder" :class="isShow">
        <list-category v-for="(data, index) in data.children" :key="index" :data="data" :search="search" :category-id="categoryId"></list-category>
    </ul>
  ```

**Demo below.**

```js
Vue.component('list-category', {
  template: "#lc",
  props: ['data', 'categoryId', 'search'],
  data() {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    icon() {
      return {
        'fa-plus': !this.open,
        'fa-minus': this.open,
      }
    },
    isFolder() {
      return this.data.children && this.data.children.length
    },
    isShow() {
      return this.open ? 'show' : 'hide'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.open = !this.open
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'England',
          children: [{
              id: 3,
              name: 'Chelsea',
              children: [{
                  id: 7,
                  name: 'Hazard'
                },
                {
                  id: 8,
                  name: 'Morata'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              name: 'Manchester United',
              children: [{
                  id: 9,
                  name: 'Pogba'
                },
                {
                  id: 10,
                  name: 'Lukaku'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Spain',
          children: [{
              id: 5,
              name: 'Real Madrid',
              children: [{
                  id: 11,
                  name: 'Ronaldo'
                },
                {
                  id: 12,
                  name: 'Bale'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              id: 6,
              name: 'Barcelona',
              children: [{
                  id: 13,
                  name: 'Messi'
                },
                {
                  id: 14,
                  name: 'Suarez'
                }
              ]
            },
          ]
        }
      ],
      categoryId: 7
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <ul class="filter-category" v-for="list in categories">
      <list-category :data="list" :category-id="categoryId"></list-category>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="lc">
    <li>
        <!--parent-->
        <a v-if="isFolder" href="javascript:" @click="toggle">
            <span class="fa fa-fw" :class="icon"></span> {{data.name}}
        </a>
        <!--if not folding, we do not need an binding event-->
        <a v-else href="javascript:" :title="data.name" :class="{active: data.id === categoryId}"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></span> {{data.name}}</a>
        <!--children-->
        <ul v-if="isFolder" :class="isShow">
            <list-category v-for="(data, index) in data.children" :key="index" :data="data" :search="search" :category-id="categoryId"></list-category>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

Comment: If I implement in my case, it does not work. Category hazard is not show. The result like this : https://postimg.org/image/4yu2rbjvx/. Should the result like image in my question

Comment: What gives you that style (gray background) is a CSS class. You have to find its name and replace `active` with its name in `:class="{active: data.id === categoryId}"`. E.g. if the CSS class name is `selectedcategory` you should use `:class="{selectedcategory: data.id === categoryId}"`.

Comment: The category hazard active. But the parent category is not show. Should the parent category show like my image in the my question

Comment: So, if I implement in the my case, the category hazard active. But the parent category(category england and category chelsea) is not directly open when script executed. I must click the parent category first. Should the hazard category active, the parent category directly open

Comment: In the code you posted, there's nothing related to opening/closing categories. Every category is always open... See the demo I posted, nothing related to opening/closing.

Comment: in my code,  there exist data open and computed isShow, isFolder,  method toogle.  It used to show and hide

Comment: Look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/vxLhbo5m/844/. I add my css. The category hazard active, but the parent category is not open

Comment: So I want the parent category open when the child category active. In my demo in jsfiddle, the parent category is not open. Should it's open. In my jsfiddle, I had implement your code

Comment: Add this code on your mounted hook: `mounted() {
    let isDataOpen = (d) => d.id === this.categoryId || d.children && d.children.some(isDataOpen);
   this.open = isDataOpen(this.data);
  },` Your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/vxLhbo5m/849/ Basically it checks if the component has the `data.id === categoryId` or if any of its children does. If so, it marks itself as opened.

Comment: Okay thanks. Seems it works. I want to ask again. Look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/vxLhbo5m/861/. I update your jsfiddle. I add filterByCategory method. So if the category clicked, the category will active. I try like that. But it must click 2x then class active. Should only click 1x, then class active. Maybe you can help me again :)

Comment: I took a stab at it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Main Vue Template

```
<ul class="filter-category" v-for="list in categories">
    <Category :data="list"></Category>
</ul>
```

Component Category Component

```
<template>
  <li style="margin-left: 1rem">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary">
      {{data.name}}
    </a>
    <ul>
      <category v-for="(data, index) in data.child_categories" 
             :key="index" :data="data"></category>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>

<script setup>
import {computed, inject, onBeforeMount, onUpdated, reactive, ref, 
watch} from "vue";
const props = defineProps(['data','category_id'])
let data = props.data;


</script>
```